# Leaflet.js, marker icons size

Tags: javascript, leaflet, frontend

I am not very familiar with Leaflet.js nor with JS in general.

I am trying to change the size of the different marker icon types, but I can only change the size of all the markers

Here is my code
Ideally, the `wptIconUrls` will have different size icons from the others

Any ideas are welcomed

Thanks you in advance

```
<!-- more info at https://formkeep.com/guides/contact-form-hugo -->
{{/* <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="https://formkeep.com/f/{{ $id }}" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="utf8" value="✓">
    {{ if $redirect }}<input type="hidden" name="_redirect_url" value="{{ $redirect }}"> {{ end }}
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="name@example.com">
    <button type="submit">{{ $button_name }}</button>
</form>

*/}}


{{ $id := default "exampletoken" (.Get 0) }}{{ $button_name := default "Submit" (.Get 1) }}{{ $redirect := .Get 2 }}



<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.7.1/leaflet.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        img {
            box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 60px rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
            -moz-border-radius:25px;
            border-radius:10px;
        }

        .gpx {
            width: 90%;
            margin: 1em auto;
        }

        .gpx header {}

        .gpx h3 {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .gpx .start {
            font-size: smaller;
        }

        .gpx .map {
            border-left: none;
            border-right: none;
            /* make the width and height to be responsive to the screen */
            width: 100%;
            height: 500px;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .gpx ul.info {
            list-style: none;
        }

        .gpx ul.info li {
            padding: 1px;
            display: inline;
        }

        .gpx ul.info {
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-size: smaller;
          }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <section id="demo" class="gpx" data-gpx-source="{{ $id }}" data-map-target="demo-map">
        <header>
            <h3>Loading...</h3>
            <ul class="info">
                <li>Distance:&nbsp;<span class="distance"></span>&nbsp;mi</li>
                <li> <a href="{{ $id }}" download>Download GPX</a>
                    </span></li>
            </ul> <span class="start"></span>
        </header>

        <article>
            <div class="map" id="demo-map"></div>
        </article>

    </section>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.7.1/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet-gpx/1.5.1/gpx.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript">
        function display_gpx(elt) {
            if (!elt) return;

            var url = elt.getAttribute('data-gpx-source');
            var mapid = elt.getAttribute('data-map-target');
            if (!url || !mapid) return;

            function _t(t) { return elt.getElementsByTagName(t)[0]; }
            function _c(c) { return elt.getElementsByClassName(c)[0]; }

            var map = L.map(mapid);
            L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.osm.org">OpenStreetMap</a>'
            }).addTo(map);

            var control = L.control.layers(null, null).addTo(map);


            new L.GPX(url, {
                async: true,
                marker_options: {
                    startIconUrl: 'https://github.com/stiliajohny/stiliajohny.github.io/raw/master/static/green-pin.png',

                    endIconUrl: 'https://github.com/stiliajohny/stiliajohny.github.io/raw/master/static/red-pin.png',
                    shadowUrl: 'https://github.com/stiliajohny/stiliajohny.github.io/raw/master/static/pin-shadow.png',
                    wptIconUrls: {
                        '': 'https://github.com/stiliajohny/stiliajohny.github.io/raw/master/static/yellow-pin.png',
                    },
                    iconSize: [24, 24],
                    iconAnchor: [10, 24],
                    shadowAnchor: [12, 28],
                    shadowSize: [36, 36],

                },
            }).on('loaded', function (e) {
                var gpx = e.target;

                map.fitBounds(gpx.getBounds());
                control.addOverlay(gpx, gpx.get_name());

                /*
                 * Note: the code below relies on the fact that the demo GPX file is
                 * an actual GPS track with timing and heartrate information.
                 */
                _t('h3').textContent = gpx.get_name();
                _c('distance').textContent = gpx.get_distance_imp().toFixed(2);

            }).addTo(map);
        }

        display_gpx(document.getElementById('demo'));
    </script>
</body>
```